# What does error "call was rejected by callee" mean?

Tags: g1ant

When running the following code, an error occurs at line 4:

> call was rejected by callee"

```
excel.open

window ✱Excel

keyboard ‴Remember, remember!‴

excel.setvalue value ‴The fifth of November‴ row 2 colindex 1

excel.setvalue value ‴The Gunpowder treason and plot‴ row 3 colname A

excel.getvalue row 1 colname A result ♥guy

dialog ♥guy
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because in the 3rd line you are in the middle of editing an excel cell (the cursor is active). You can't edit two cells at once, so I have two solutions for you.

1. Don't use `keyboard`, insert values using `excel.setvalue`
2. Use `keyboard` but press enter to finish editing a cell.

```
excel.open
window ✱Excel✱
keyboard ‴Remember, remember!⋘enter⋙‴
excel.setvalue value ‴The fifth of November‴ row 2 colindex 1
excel.setvalue value ‴The Gunpowder treason and plot‴ row 3 colname A
excel.getvalue row 1 colname A result ♥guy
dialog ♥guy
```